# Libgdx - TextureRegion.flip()

Tags: android, libgdx, 2d

I have a problem with TextureRegion. When I fliped TextureAtlas, my character will move only in right direction (where TextureAtlas was flipped), and won't go back to left direction. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Code is below:

```
TextureAtlas atlas  = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("texture/textures.pack"));
TextureRegion[] walkLeftFrame = new TextureRegion[5]; 
for(int i = 0 ; i<5; i++){
            walkLeftFrame[i] = atlas.findRegion("bob-0"+(i+2));
}
walkLeftAnimation = new Animation(RUNNING_FRAME_DURATION , walkLeftFrame); 

TextureRegion[] walkRightFrame = new TextureRegion[5];
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            walkRightFrame[i] = atlas.findRegion("bob-0" + (i + 2));
            walkRightFrame[i].flip(true, false);
}
walkRightAnimation = new Animation(RUNNING_FRAME_DURATION, walkRightFrame);


if(bob.isFacingLeft())
              bobFrame = walkLeftAnimation.getKeyFrame(bob.getStateTime(), true);
else 
              bobFrame = walkRightAnimation.getKeyFrame(bob.getStateTime(), true);


 spriteBatch.draw(bobFrame, bob.getPosition().x * ppuX , bob.getPosition().y * ppuY , Bob.SIZE *ppuX, Bob.SIZE * ppuY);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the typical call by reference problem.

> call by value
>
> In call by value, a copy of actual arguments is passed to formal
>   arguments of the called function and any change made to the formal
>   arguments in the called function have no effect on the values of
>   actual arguments in the calling function.
>
> call by reference
>   In call by reference, the location (address) of
>   actual arguments is passed to formal arguments of the called function.
>   This means by accessing the addresses of actual arguments we can alter
>   them within from the called function.

That means you are accessing the same TextureRegions in both arrays. That's why all your Regions are flipped.

Something like this should work:

```
TextureRegion[] walkRightFrame = new TextureRegion[5];
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            walkRightFrame[i] = new TextureRegion(atlas.findRegion("bob-0" + (i + 2)));
            walkRightFrame[i].flip(true, false);
}
```